# ssl error why installing with pip

Tags: python, ssl, pip

Im trying to install pyobjc with pip. However every time i run it i get this error. Some forums say to use --trusted as a workaround but it still doesn't work. My computer is a Mac OS Sierra version 10.12.6

My command :

```
$ sudo pip install pyobjc-framework-Quartz
```

> Collecting pyobjc-framework-Quartz   Retrying (Retry(total=4,
>   connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection
>   broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]
>   certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:833)'),)':
>   /simple/pyobjc-framework-quartz/   Retrying (Retry(total=3,
>   connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection
>   broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]
>   certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:833)'),)':
>   /simple/pyobjc-framework-quartz/   Retrying (Retry(total=2,
>   connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection
>   broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]
>   certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:833)'),)':
>   /simple/pyobjc-framework-quartz/   Retrying (Retry(total=1,
>   connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection
>   broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]
>   certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:833)'),)':
>   /simple/pyobjc-framework-quartz/   Retrying (Retry(total=0,
>   connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection
>   broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]
>   certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:833)'),)':
>   /simple/pyobjc-framework-quartz/   Could not fetch URL
>   https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyobjc-framework-quartz/: There was a
>   problem confirming the ssl certificate:
>   HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443): Max retries
>   exceeded with url: /simple/pyobjc-framework-quartz/ (Caused by
>   SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate
>   verify failed (_ssl.c:833)'),)) - skipping   Could not find a version
>   that satisfies the requirement pyobjc-framework-Quartz (from versions:
>   ) No matching distribution found for pyobjc-framework-Quartz

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install fails with "connection error: \[SSL: CERTIFICATE\_VERIFY\_FAILED\] certificate verify failed (\_ssl.c:598)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981703/pip-install-fails-with-connection-error-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certi)

Comment: remove the apt or mac package version of pip and install it with easy_install ... and then use pip to upgrade itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can run with this command:

```
sudo pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --trusted-host pypi.org pyobjc-framework-Quartz
```